# Растяжение логотипа и гамбургера при изменении ширины экрана с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

В связи с вопросом [Выравнивание логотипа с помощью css](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1394565/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-css-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-vw) возник вопрос:

"Как с помощью javascript при расширении размера окна веб-браузера добиться того, чтобы положение и размеры логотипа и гамбургера изменялись пропорционально?  Также как изменить позиционирование логотипа и гамбургера при растяжении экрана?"

Вопрос, который сочтен дубликатом, был отвечен мною же и в десятки раз проще примера в этом вопросе. В этом примере гораздо больше взаимосвязанных элементов, чем в приведенном вопросе (то был скорее учебный пример, а это боевой). Мне нужен javascript подход.

Comment: Можно узнать почему именно через JavaScript, если через CSS можно этого добиться?

Comment: @EzioMercer через css были попытки на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1394565/Выравнивание-логотипа-с-помощью-css-Позиционирование-изображения-в-или-vw сделать это. Я не понял как это можно сделать через css, поэтому спросил как это сделать на javascript.

Comment: @EzioMercer У них в чате был довольно долгий, как я понял, разговор. Не получается у человека с помощью css сверстать динамический(адаптивный) макет. Какой-то блок не желает верно работать. Видимо кто-то сдался и решил залепить костылем через JS что я делать не советую. Попробуйте с переводчиком в руках(если он нужен) обратиться на stack - en. ^^

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato Я просто реально не понимаю, для разных экранов существует `@media` для пропорциональных отсутпов существуют проценты и `vw` ну или родительскому элементу задать `display: flex` и управлять через него. На чистом CSS пишут игры, а тут просто отступы хотят через JS. На счёт того что "забили" - это ещё хуже, потому что требуют дать говнокод, только потому что не ответили на адекватный вопрос. У меня на нынешней работе я удаляю огромные куски JS, потому что кто-то поленился через пару строчек CSS что-то исправить

Comment: @wfamilyweb Запомните JS это самый крайний рубеж для того чтобы менять стили. Нужно использовать только если у вас есть функционала который требует участия JS, например если вы ширину и высоту назначаете через пользовательский ввод. Через JS можно и нужно добавлять/удалять классы и управлять аттрибутами

Comment: Я советую немного отвлечься от вашей страницы, и сверстать отдельно по "фану" динамическую страничку, и разобраться в конце концов как это работает, а после опять вернуться к своему проекту и исправить, как вам кажется не исправимое. Если продолжите искать истошно разные решения, можете перегореть! Так что отвлекитесь на что нибудь другое. Удачи